# Request additional permission for XHR only, not for browsing history

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to develop extension that will allow me to monitor total progress of all downloads. I'd like to get total percentage of all currently downloading items and do a XHR request to report my progress.

I have problem with permissions that are required to make XHR request.

My manifest.json:

```
{"name": "__MSG_extName__",
 "version": "0.3",
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "description": "__MSG_extDesc__",
 "icons": {"128": "icon128.png"},
 "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": {
     "19": "icon19.png",
     "38": "icon38.png"},
   "default_title": "__MSG_extName__",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "options_ui": {
    "page": "options.html",
    "chrome_style": true
  },
 "background": {"persistent": false, "scripts": ["background.js"]},
 "default_locale": "en",
 "optional_permissions": ["http://*/", "https://*/", "tabs"],
 "permissions": ["downloads"]
 }
```

as You can see initially I'm requesting only `downloads` permission, but I'd like to allow end user to specify his endpoint URL using options page:

[image]

Unfortunately when requesting for permissions I get this question:
[image]

Which isn't what I really need. I only need permissions to do XHR request to specific URL, I don't need `Read your browsing history` permission.

Here is how I'm asking for permissions:

```
var getLocation = function(href) {
    var l = document.createElement("a");
    l.href = href;
    return l;
};
var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
var l = getLocation(url);
var newUrl = l.protocol+'//'+l.hostname+'/';
chrome.permissions.request({
    permissions: ['tabs'],
    origins: [newUrl]
    }, function(granted) {
    if (granted) {
      console.log('OK');
    } else {
      console.log('NIE');
    }
});
```

I suppose I can't change first permission from `Read and change your data on 192.168.10.101` to `Make requests to 192.168.10.101`, but can I get rid of second permission?

I've tried changing my request code to this:

```
chrome.permissions.request({
    permissions: [newUrl],
    origins: [newUrl]
    }, function(granted) {
    if (granted) {
      console.log('OK');
    } else {
      console.log('NIE');
    }
});
```

but I get this exception:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError while running permissions.request:
>   'http://www.example.com' is not a recognized permission.

I don't want to add `"http://*/"` to permissions because I won't be doing requests to all possible addresses, just to single one and I want to allow user to set it up and change if needed.

Comment: FYI, `tabs` permission is displayed as "Read your browsing history". You don't need it, see the [official example](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/permissions/extension-questions/options.js)

Comment: @wOxxOm if I'm requesting permissions I must pass `permissions` and `origins`. If I understand correctly origins is the url, but I must pass something in permissions, I've tried passing same url as in origins but this didn't work. I can replace `tabs` but with what?

Comment: @wOxxOm sorry for not reading twice before I commented. I can just remove `permissions` from requests. That solved my issue partially. Thank You!